# How to detect button click in googlemaps infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Using Googlemaps V3

I am trying to add a button to the infoWindow on my googlemap. The infoWindows and button appear as expected. I am trying to capture the onclick event of the button. This is what I have so far:

```
var contentBtn = '<p><button id="marker'+numby+'" class="iwLink" href="#" >Done</button></p>';
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(address+contentBtn);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(contentBtn, 'click', function() {

          alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
```

The infoWindow appears as expected, along with the button. However, I also get the following error in the console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
>   This appears to be caused by the line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(contentBtn, 'click', function()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button isn't added to the DOM until the infowindow completes rendering.  You can't find it with getElementById (or the jquery equivalent) until after the [infowindow domready event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) fires.

```
var contentBtn = '<p><button id="marker'+numby+'" class="iwLink" href="#" >Done</button></p>';
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(address+contentBtn);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(contentBtn, 'click', function() {

        alert($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    });
```